# Getting DebugBreak to work in Fortran

Tags: fortran, debugbreak

I found the following article:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-fortran-compiler-microsoft-debugging-function-debugbreak/

Unfortunately when I tried to implement this code and compiled I received the following error:

Error 1 error #7286: This symbol has multiply declared DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS attribute.   [DEBUGBREAK] 176

I'm using the Intel FORTRAN compiler.

Any additional insights is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get an answer here, since this is a question about a particular product, you might get an answer in one of Intel's Fortran Forums: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/